# I am trying to execute an exe in Java which is developed in Dotnet

Tags: java, java-8

The code in java was made to run a .exe file created in .NET platform and the code was shown to be running successfully. The process even showed to be alive when called with isAlive() function but doesn't run. The .exe did not run, i.e. was not shown anywhere in task manager. Also I checked it with waitFor() methood.

Further i need to run this on a Java Servlet please suggest me if what i can do to make this run, Thanks in advance

The code is as below:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("D:\\J2EEeclipse-workspace\\TARecruiter\\WebContent\\WEB-INF\\Debug\\Sharpenter.RP.UI.Console.exe");
        Process p=pb.start();
        System.err.println( p.waitFor());
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: add `pb.redirectErrorStream(true);  pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);` to see if any error is given

Comment: Or just `inheritIO()`…

Comment: @Holger it does not work even

Comment: @azro still it is not showing output or any process started in task manager and if i am running same in dot net it works as desired, I think if dot net to able to achieve same then why not Java

Comment: Your problem description is inconsistent. You should elaborate on how “the code was shown to be running successfully”. `isAlive()` should never report `true` when you called `waitFor()` previously, as `waitFor()`’s purpose is precisely to wait until the process is not alive anymore. Besides that, you can’t do `p.waitFor()+p.isAlive()` which would add an `int` to a `boolean`, so that code of your question is clearly not the code you ever tried…

Comment: These two separate instances where i attempted both isAlive and waitFor

Comment: How are you running it in .net? You can try, `Files.exists(Paths.get("yourpathname"))` to make sure you're pointing to your file.

Comment: @matt, before posting my query here I had checked this and yes file path was correct. till now what i have figured out is is it the problem of Java.exe or Javaw.exe as eclipse Ide Run the code without terminal operations I think.

Comment: It can be that you need an interactive tty to use the program, hence the program would start briefly, and finish running. That is why people are telling you to capture the stdout/err and see if it says anything. Also you might need to use the stdin. There is a good library [ztexec](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec) which is great, but I don't know if it will help with the shell/cmd line issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below-provided code-snippet would work and initiate the process. Which can be viewable in the task manager. To make it work currently create a .java code with the provided snippet in the folder where the .exe file exists and run the code. Now you can make this code as a thread and call anywhere in your program as a thread to make it work. This certainly is not the final solution, but until the time I get to the actual reason keep working.

```
try {
Process 
 p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Sharpenter.ResumeParser.UI.Console.exe");
                       try{    p.waitFor();
                          }catch (InterruptedException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
}

                              System.out.println("Done.");

 } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: it worked, so what i need to do to make use of it into a Servlet actually it was required to be called from a Servlet .